# Remove LXDM and start DE via startx/startlxde

Tags: lxde, lxdm

I want to remove **lxdm** and start **lxde** with just **startx** or **startlxde**.

I previously just had an **openbox** installation and was building that up. I then installed **lxde**, but wanted to get rid of **lxdm**, so I uninstalled it. Upon doing so, typing **startx** or **startlxde** kicks me into the previous **openbox** session and not into the **lxde** session. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you've removed lxdm and booting into command line. Why not install another desktop manager, instead of lxdm ? For instance `sudo apt-get install gdm` or `sudo apt-get install lightdm` ? In fact, if you installed lxde after installing ubuntu, lightdm should be on your machine already. You chould switch to it with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and change the session from there.

You could also specify the default desktop session in the file `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/yourusernamehere` , specifically on line 12, where it says XSession

[image]

If what you want is to boot into command line and then start x server manually, here's what you can do:

Open `/etc/default/grub` with your favorite text editor (note, you must use sudo)

and edit line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"`, which is in screenshot bellow is line 12

[image]

Save the file, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot once done. Once you boot up, you will be prompted to login into tty, run `sudo service lightdm start`, where lightdm is whatever greeter/desktop manager you want to use or have

Alternatively you could start openbox session with the following command:
`openbox --replace` directly from lxde (wont work in tty)

Among other things, you could do `sudo service lightdm start && openbox --replace` as oneliner, or put it into a script

Answer (score 0):

Your .xinitrc file will need to be changed to start lxde instead of openbox. Open a terminal, and type `nano ~/.xinitrc`. You should see a line that says "exec openbox-session". Comment that line out by adding a "#" as the first character. Then, add a line that says `exec lxde-session`.

The xinit manpage offers a more complete description of what this file does, but basically, it's the file that startx looks at to decide what to do, and what order to do it in. [Here's the manpage for ubuntu's xinit file.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/xinit.1.html)

If that doesn't work, the LXDE wiki also has the following instructions [on their wiki](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Ubuntu):

No display manager, use startx
Run following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

Then choose startlxde. The next time you run startx, LXDE will be started.

Comment: I'd came across the LXDE wiki article before and tried that. Also, edited .xinitrc and it says no lxde-session found when I try to run startx. Any other ideas?  I have an auto and manual startlxde, and I believe I've tried both.

Comment: Sorry to have kept you waiting. Maybe try re-installing lxde to see if any dependencies have gone missing? Please let us know what you've tried in the meantime, especially if you've gotten it to work.